The power of a Neyman Pearson test is strictly greater than its level
Let $X \sim p$, where $p \in \{ p_0, p_1 \}$ is some density. We want to test $H_0:p=p_0$ vs $H_1:p=p_1$.
Best way to do it is to build the Neyman Pearson test $\Phi_{NP}$ of level $\alpha=\mathbb{E}_{p_0}[\Phi_{NP}]$.
Then its power $\beta= \mathbb{E}_{p_1}[\Phi_{NP}]$ is strictly greater than $\alpha$, i.e. we have $\alpha < \beta$.
It is relatively easy to show $\alpha \leq \beta$ by considering the test $\tilde{\Phi}(x) \equiv \alpha$, but I don't see how to show the stronger result.
Edit: it is a duplicate, apologies
Power and size relation in Hypothesis testing.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3792658/321264

Yeah it is a duplicate, sorry I couldn't find it

The statement we want to prove is that given $\mathbb{P}_0 \neq \mathbb{P}_1$, we have $\mathbb{E}_1[\phi] = \beta > \alpha = \mathbb{E}_0[\phi]$, where $\phi$ is the uniformly best test given by the Neyman-Pearson lemma.
The approach I would take is to assume that $\alpha = \beta$ and to show that $\mathbb{P}_0 = \mathbb{P}_1$.
Since $\phi$ is a uniformly best test (UBT), so is $\alpha$. Then, by the Neyman-Pearson lemma,
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \begin{cases}1, \quad \text{if } p_1 > kp_0 \text{ a.e. for appropriate } k \in [0, \infty) \\
0, \quad \text{if } p_1 < kp_0\end{cases}
\end{align*}
However, since $\alpha \in (0,1)$, we have that $p_1 = kp_0$ a.s. Then,
$$ 1 = \mathbb{P}_1(\Omega) = \int_\Omega p_1 d\mu = k \int_\Omega p_0 d\mu = k\mathbb{P}_0(\Omega) = k$$
where $\Omega$ is observation space. So, since $1 = k$, we have that $p_0 = p_1$ a.s., and so $\mathbb{P}_0 = \mathbb{P}_1$. Note that I took the densities $p_0, p_1$ to be densities of the probability measures $\mathbb{P}_0, \mathbb{P}_1$ with respect to some reference measure $\mu$.

For reference, this is the version of the Neyman-Pearson lemma we learned in my mathematical statistics class:
Lemma: Given the hypothesis test setting you gave with probability measures and densities as defined above, the following holds:
(a) Let $\phi: \Omega \longrightarrow [0,1]$ be a test with

$\mathbb{E}_0 = \alpha$, i.e. $\phi$ test at level $\alpha$
$\exists k \in [0, \infty)$ with $ \phi = \begin{cases}1, \quad \text{if } p_1 > kp_0 \text{ a.e.} \\
0, \quad \text{if } p_1 < kp_0\end{cases}$ $(**)$

Then, $\mathbb{E}_1[\phi] = \max_{\phi \text{ test at level } \alpha} \mathbb{E}_1[\phi]$ $(*)$
(b) $\forall \alpha \in (0, 1) \exists $ test $\phi$ as in (a)
(c) Every test $\phi$ at level $\alpha$ satisfying $(*)$ also satisfies $(**)$. If, additionally, $\mathbb{E}[\phi] < 1$, then $\mathbb{E}_0[\phi] = \alpha$ (i.e. 1. holds)
